# Закончить merge без хуков

Tags: git, git-merge

Хочу завершить merge

```
git merge --continue
```

но так, чтобы не запускались прекоммитные хуки.

Пытался добавить в команду опцию `-n`, но похоже, что она несовместима с `--continue`.

Comment: временно переименовать файлы с hook-ами?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, ну это костыль какой-то... Нормальных способов нет, типа как-то commit использовать вместо merge ли ещё что-то? В графических оболочках мёрдж завершается кнопкой commit.

Comment: Так изначально запускайте слияние без звуков, или я что-то не так понимаю ?

Comment: @0andriy, а так можно? В смысле, оно сработает?

Answer (score 0):

Судя по официальной документации, `git merge` поддерживает только полное название ключа: `--no-verify`, потому что сокращение `-n` занято для других целей.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge

> В графических оболочках мёрдж завершается кнопкой commit

На той же странице написано: После разрешения конфликтов используйте `git commit` или `git merge --continue`

Comment: Не работает: `git merge --continue --no-verify` выдаёт `fatal: --continue expects no arguments` независимо от порядка флагов.

Comment: Если использовать `commit`, то непонятно, получится ли сгенерированное сообщение о коммите или его придётся писать самому.